# EPiServer: Get friendly URL with language flag?

Tags: c#, episerver

My variable `langURL` currently returns a non-friendly url like so: http://localhost:57299/link/457fee1669e348febf67ecb57b281945.aspx?epslanguage=de-AT

Is it possible to get a friendly url?

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this PageData currentPage)
{

    var availablePageLanguages = currentPage.ExistingLanguages.Select(culture => culture.Name).ToArray();
    var Output = "";
    var langURL = "";

    foreach (string listitem in availablePageLanguages)
    {
        langURL = EPiServer.Web.UriUtil.AddLanguageSelection(currentPage.LinkURL, listitem);
        Output += "<link href=\"" + langURL + "\" hreflang=\"" + listitem + "\" rel=\"alternate\" >";
    }


    // Dictionary<String, String>
    return new HtmlString(Output.ToString());
}
```

For each page I would like to get the friendly urls with the language flag as well, for example:

- /
- /de-DE
- /en-DE

Comment: Please consider that the page can also have fallback languages. I'm pretty sure they are not returned by calling `currentPage.ExistingLanguages`.

Comment: looking at your code, most probably all you need is `@Html.AlternateLinks()` https://world.episerver.com/documentation/class-library/?documentId=cms/11/C318F94B

Answer (score 2):

Luckily we don't need to deal with the `LinkURL` property anymore. Instead, I would use the `UrlResolver` for this.

Your code could be quickly rewritten to something like this:

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this PageData currentPage)
{
    // StringBuilder usually performs better than concatenating a variable number of strings.
    var sb = new StringBuilder;

    foreach (string language in currentPage.ExistingLanguages.Select(culture => culture.Name))
    {
        // Get the URL to the page in the individual languages, respecting the
        // website language settings (sometimes a language is bound to another hostname)
        string url = UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(currentPage.ContentLink, language);
        sb.AppendLine($"<link href=\"{url}\" hreflang=\"{language}\" rel=\"alternate\"/>");
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

But I usually implement something like this as a Razor helper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.
Try this:

```
public string GetExternalUrl(string linkUrl)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var url = new UrlBuilder(linkUrl);
                Global.UrlRewriteProvider.ConvertToExternal(url, linkUrl, Encoding.UTF8);
                result = url.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return result;
        }
```